# get Specific JSON Response Value

Tags: php, json

json response as below:

```
{"Success":true,"ErrorCode":0,"UserInformation":{"UserID":"19"}......
```

how do I get the `UserID` value by using `json_decode`?

I tried the below code with no luck.

```
$Response = json_decode($Response[2]);
echo $Response[0][0][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<?php

$json = '{"Success":true, "ErrorCode":"0","UserInformation":{"UserID":"19"}}';
$response = json_decode($json, true);

echo $userId = $response["UserInformation"]["UserID"];

?>
```

Please check the PHP documentation of json_decode at http://php.net/json_decode 
You can use object as well if you skip the second parameter of the json_decode function.